# R Iterating through data frame by comparing the previous value in the same column to the next

Tags: r, loops

**I have this dataset**

[image]

Where I want to find out the Cell_Number_~ where the value of column Cell_Length_in_~ doubled in respect to the previous Value.
That should be iterative for the Value of Seedling first and then for the condition.

Sorry for maybe being not so clear. I'm very new to this.

Comment: You mean `Seedling` should be treated as a grouping column?

Comment: So the result should be the Value of Cell_Number_from~ at the row where the Value of Cell_Length_in_~ doubled. This should be applied to every Group of Seedling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we `group_by` `Seedling` to `filter` out rows where the `Cell_Length_in` value is at least twice as large as the `lag`ging one:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Seedling) %>%
  filter(
    Cell_Length_in > 2 * lag(Cell_Length_in)
  )
# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   Seedling [3]
  Seedling Cell_Number_from Cell_Length_in
     <dbl>            <int>          <dbl>
1        1                3           4   
2        2                6          26.7 
3        2                8          24.8 
4        3               12           0.21
```

Toy data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Seedling = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
  Cell_Number_from = 1:12,
  Cell_Length_in = c(2,1,4,1,
                     12.5,26.7,11.1,24.8,
                     0.2,0.2,0.1,0.21)
)
```

**EDIT**:

To retrieve only the first doubled value per group, add `slice_head`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Seedling) %>%
  filter(
    Cell_Length_in > 2 * lag(Cell_Length_in)
  ) %>%
  slice_head()
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Groups:   Seedling [3]
  Seedling Cell_Number_from Cell_Length_in
     <dbl>            <int>          <dbl>
1        1                3           4   
2        2                6          26.7 
3        3               12           0.21
```

Comment: But is there a way to only receive the first value that doubled?

Comment: The first doubled value per group, right? See edited answer.

Comment: That works just fine. Thank you, Chris!